# Problema com legenda no ggplot, usando duplo eixo y + geom_line()+geom_point() x geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Olá, estou com outro problema em relação a apresentação de legenda, neste caso, usando eixo y duplo (`ggplot::scale_y_continuous::sec_axis`), e `geom_line()+geom_point()` x `geom_bar()`, conforme observa-se na figura 1. Gostaria de apresentar a legenda como um quadrado sem linha e ponto colorido, identificando "UR" e 3 quadrados, com as legendas para "Tmáx", "Tméd" e "Tmín", com seus respectivos `shape`, `linetype`, e `colour`.

Obs: eu estou usando o pacote `extrafont`, para a fonte "Times New Roman".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)

novo<-structure(list(AVA=c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,
11L,12L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L,
1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L),variable=structure(c(1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,3L),.Label=c("Tar","Tarmin","Tarmax"),class="factor"),
value=c(26.9102916666667,26.0853333333333,27.8317291666667,
28.3282083333333,27.4253958333333,30.3683196875,25.3293125,
26.888375,22.8657708333333,26.8046458333333,23.222375,
23.4121041666667,22.08,21.887,25.673,23.925,23.861,
25.705,20.45,21.919,17.265,21.49,19.581,18.251,32.012,
31.057,31.089,32.762,32.001,34.997005,30.542,31.851,
27.85,32.516,27.518,28.612)),row.names=c(NA,-36L),class="data.frame")

UR<-structure(list(AVA=1:12,variable=structure(c(1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L),.Label="UR",class="factor"),
value=c(74.4006458333333,74.8331458333333,78.3165833333333,
73.8219375,78.0607708333333,68.2176286458333,69.2232916666667,
67.881625,64.4237916666667,64.3282083333333,66.3142916666667,
70.0928125)),row.names=c(NA,-12L),class="data.frame")

ggplot(novo,aes(x=AVA,y=value,group=variable,colour=variable))+geom_point(aes(shape=variable),cex=1.5)+geom_line(aes(linetype=variable),cex=1.2)+
  scale_y_continuous(name = expression("Temperatura do ar("^"o"*"C )"),limits=c(0,40),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *2,name=expression("Umidade relativa do ar (%)")))+
  geom_bar(data=UR,aes(x=AVA,y=value/2,colour=variable),alpha=.2,stat="identity",width = .25)+
  scale_shape_manual("",breaks=c("Tar","Tarmax","Tarmin","UR"),values=c(15,16,18),labels=c("Tméd","Tmáx","Tmín","UR ar"))+
  scale_linetype_manual("",breaks=c("Tar","Tarmax","Tarmin","UR"),values=c(1,2,4),labels=c("Tméd","Tmáx","Tmín","UR ar"))+
  scale_fill_manual("",breaks=c("Tar","Tarmax","Tarmin","UR"),values=c("purple"),labels=c("Tméd","Tmáx","Tmín","UR ar"))+
  scale_colour_manual("",labels=c("Tméd","Tmáx","Tmín","UR ar"),breaks=c("Tar","Tarmax","Tarmin","UR"),values=c("black","red","blue","purple"))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1.5), angle = 90),text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12),
        legend.text = element_text(size=12,face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está definindo cor e grupo na estética global, o que fará com que sejam aplicadas à todas geometrias. Coloque na global os parâmetros que valem para todas e nas estéticas das geometrias o que se aplica apenas à cada uma delas. O mesmo vale para as escalas.

```
labs <- c("Temperatura", labels = c("média", "mínima", "máxima"))

ggplot(novo,aes(AVA, value)) +
  geom_col(data = UR, aes(y = value/2, fill = variable), colour = "black", alpha=.3, width = .25) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = variable, colour = variable), cex = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = variable, colour = variable), cex = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = "#6baed6") +
  scale_color_manual(labs, values = c("black", "blue", "red")) +
  scale_shape_manual(labs, values = c(15, 16, 18)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(labs, values = c(1, 2, 4)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Temperatura (ºC)", sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2, "Umidade relativa (%)"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Removi o tema para facilitar a reprodução. Algumas observações:

- `geom_col` é o atalho para usar barras com `stat = identity`
- para barras, `color` representa a cor da linha externa, use `fill` para a cor da barra em si
- as geometrias são plotadas na ordem; coloque `geom_col` primeiro se quiser que ela fique de fundo.
- use `NULL` ao invés de `""` nos títulos de legenda; isso corresponde à usar `element_blank`
- cores, formatos, etc que serão exibidos em legenda vão dentro do `aes()` e a personalização vai na `scale_*` correspondente. Os que não variam e não serão exibidos em legenda vão fora do `aes`

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, embora seja intuitivo de usar o `ggplot2` tem umas particularidades, que as vezes nos faz quebrar a cabeça, não seria tão mais fácil se eles tivessem colocado uma forma de editar a legenda, como no `lattice`, que você faz o que precisa dentro de `key=list()`.

Comment: Cheque a ajuda para `guides`. GGplot é modular, todo componente pode ser armazenado em objeto.